# System.NullPointerException : Constructor argument can not be null

Tags: apex, unit-test

My Controller class

```
public with sharing class invoiceTempController{
    public Id invId{get;set;}

    public List<FM_Invoice__c> invoiceList{get;set;}
    public List<Invoice_Details__c >invReq {get;set;}
    public String pdfName {get;set;}

    Public List<Wrapper> WrapperList {get;set;}
    Public Decimal TotalAmount {get;set;}
    public Decimal AfterDiscountTotal {get;set;} 
    public Decimal Tax {get;set;} 
    Public Decimal GrandTotal {get;set;}
    Public String Amount_in_Words{get;set;}

    public List<MM_Procurement__c>purList {get;set;}

    public invoiceTempController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        invId= controller.getRecord().id;
        //invId= 'a0E9E000001TpJT';
        WrapperList = new List<Wrapper>();
        TotalAmount = 0;
        AfterDiscountTotal = 0;
        Tax = 0;
        GrandTotal = 0;


      invoiceList = [SELECT Name,Discount__c,FM_Due_Date__c,Tax__c,FM_Invoice_ID__c,Total_Invoice_Cost__c,
                     FM_Payment_Status__c,FM_Project_Name__r.Client_Name__r.Bank_Contact_Number__c,
                     FM_Project_Name__r.Work_Order_Date__c,FM_Project_Name__r.Work_Order__c,FM_Project_Name__r.PO_No__c,
                     FM_Project_Name__r.Client_Name__r.IFSC_Code__c,FM_Project_Name__r.Client_Name__r.Account_Number__c,
                     FM_Project_Name__r.Client_Name__r.Bank_Name__c,FM_Project_Name__r.Client_Name__r.Name,
                     FM_Project_Name__r.Client_Name__r.BillingStreet,FM_Project_Name__r.Client_Name__r.BillingPostalCode,
                     FM_Project_Name__r.Client_Name__r.BillingCountry,FM_Project_Name__r.Client_Name__r.BillingCity,
                     FM_Project_Name__r.Client_Name__r.BillingState,FM_Payment_Terms__c,FM_Project_Name__c,
                     FM_Project_Name__r.PM_Start_Date__c,CreatedDate From FM_Invoice__c where Id=:invId Limit 1];

       invReq = [SELECT Id,Name,FM_Invoice_Line_Items__c,Unit_Cost__c,FM_Invoice_Line_Items__r.Name,FM_Invoice_Line_Items__r.MM_Size__c,FM_Invoice_Line_Items__r.MM_Material_Description__c,FM_Invoice_Name__c,Price__c,FM_Quantity__c,New_Quantity__c,FM_Total_Amount__c,Description__c From Invoice_Details__c where FM_Invoice_Name__c =:invoiceList[0].id];

       purList = [select id ,Name,MM_Project_Name__r.Name,MM_Purchase_Order_No__c,MM_Purchase_Order_Date__c FROM MM_Procurement__c where MM_Project_Name__c =:invoiceList[0].FM_Project_Name__c];

        Integer No=0;
        for(Invoice_Details__c ProDet : invReq ){
            string Description = '';
            if(ProDet.FM_Invoice_Line_Items__r.Name != null){
                Description = ProDet.FM_Invoice_Line_Items__r.Name+' - '+ProDet.FM_Invoice_Line_Items__r.MM_Size__c +' (' + ProDet.FM_Invoice_Line_Items__r.MM_Material_Description__c + ')';
            }else{
               Description = ProDet.Description__c;  
            }
            WrapperList.add(new Wrapper(++No,Description,ProDet.New_Quantity__c,ProDet.Price__c,ProDet.FM_Total_Amount__c,ProDet.FM_Invoice_Line_Items__r.MM_Size__c));

            TotalAmount = TotalAmount +ProDet.FM_Total_Amount__c;
            AfterDiscountTotal = TotalAmount - invoiceList[0].Discount__c;
            Tax = ((AfterDiscountTotal * invoiceList[0].Tax__c)/100).SetScale(2);
            GrandTotal = (AfterDiscountTotal + Tax).SetScale(2);


        }

            Long n = GrandTotal.longValue();
            string amo = ConvertCurrencyToWords.english_number(n);
            string amo1 = amo.remove(',');
            Amount_in_Words = amo1;

        Integer Dummy;
        String item;
        String Des;
        Decimal UP;
        String Qan;
        String matsize;

        for(integer i=37;i>invReq.size();i--){
            WrapperList.add(new Wrapper(Dummy,Des,Qan,UP,UP,matsize));
        }
    }


    Public class Wrapper{

        Public Integer slNo{get;set;}
        Public String Description { get;set;}
        Public String Quantity  { get;set;}
        Public Decimal UnitPrice {get;set;}
        Public Decimal TotalAmount {get;set;}
        public string MaterialSize {get;set;}


        Public Wrapper(Integer sno,String Des,String Quan, Decimal UP, Decimal TotAmt, String Msize){

            this.slNo = sno;
            this.Description = Des;
            this.Quantity  = Quan;
            this.UnitPrice = UP;
            this.TotalAmount = TotAmt;
            this.MaterialSize = Msize;

        }

    }  


    public PageReference savePdf() {

            PageReference pdf = new PageReference('/apex/invoiceTemplate');
            pdf.SetRedirect(true);
            // add parent id to the parameters for standardcontroller
            pdf.getParameters().put('id',invId);

            // create the new attachment
            Attachment attach = new Attachment();

            // the contents of the attachment from the pdf
            Blob body;

            try {

                // returns the output of the page as a PDF
                body = pdf.getContentAsPDF();

            // need to pass unit test -- current bug    
            } catch (VisualforceException e) {
                body = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');
            }

            attach.Body = body;
            // add the user entered name
            attach.Name = 'invoice';
            attach.IsPrivate = false;
            // attach the pdf to the account
            attach.ParentId = invId;
            attach.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
            insert attach;

            FM_Invoice__c proc = new FM_Invoice__c();
            proc.FM_Payment_Status__c = 'Generated Invoice';
            proc.id=invId;
            update proc;

            // send the user to the account to view results
            return new PageReference('/'+invId);
            //return pdf;
    }
}
```

My test class

```
@isTest
public class Test_InvoiceTempController {
   @isTest
    public static void tester(){
        //custom setting
        TestDataFactory1.createSampleOryxPASSMSC();

        PageReference p=new PageReference('/apex/test');
        Test.setCurrentPage(p);
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TestCalloutMock());
        User u=TestDataFactory1.createSampleUser();
        Account acc=TestDataFactory1.createSampleAccount();
        PM_Project__c testProject=TestDataFactory1.createSampleProject();
        MM_Material__c testMaterial=TestDataFactory1.createMaterial();
        Material_Allocation__c testMaterialAlloc=TestDataFactory1.createSampleMaterialAllocation();
        MM_Material_Allocation_Request__c testMAR=TestDataFactory1.createSampleMaterialAllocationRequest();
        MM_Material_Dispatched__c testMD=TestDataFactory1.createSampleMaterialDispatched();
        FM_Invoice__c invoice=TestDataFactory1.createSampleInvoice();
        Invoice_Details__c invd=TestDataFactory1.createSampleInvoiceDetails();

        ApexPages.StandardController controller=new ApexPages.StandardController(invoice);
        invoiceTempController inv=new invoiceTempController(controller);//Error here(Controller is null)
        System.debug('invoice list' +inv.invoiceList);
        invoiceTempController.Wrapper wrap=new invoiceTempController.Wrapper(1,'c','1',1,100,'5');
        inv.WrapperList.add(wrap);        
        inv.savePdf();
        inv.pdfName='ave';
        inv.TotalAmount=1;
        inv.Amount_in_Words='abc';

    }
}
```

How to resolve this plz help me out...

Comment: is it failed in test-class only, or have stack trace to class under test too?

Comment: can you provide full error message?

Comment: Errors : System.NullPointerException : Constructor argument can not be null Stack trace :  Class.invoiceTempController.: line 53, column 1 Class.Test_InvoiceTempController.tester: line 27, column 1

Comment: actually you have error not in test class, but class under test. Line 53. Can you provide this line number of class under test?

Comment: debug what value has `invoiceList[0].Discount__c` ?

Comment: You can use ternary operator like- TotalAmount - (invoiceList[0].Discount__c != null ? invoiceList[0].Discount__c : 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have error not in test class, but class under test. Line 53.

debug what value has `invoiceList[0].Discount__c`. Seems like it is `null` and it is a source of exception